# Is Proverbs 13:7a properly translated as 'pretends' or 'makes'?

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy

I find two alternatives in English translations of Proverbs 13:7a.

> New American Standard: There is one who **pretends** to be rich, but
> has nothing

vs

> King James: There is one who **makes himself** rich, yet has nothing

In both the Masoretic and the Westminster Leningrad Codex, the word in question is מִתְעַשֵּׁר , root word is עָשַׁר. The Strong's number for the root word is H6238, translated 'enrich.'

The lessons found in one who pretends to be rich but has nothing, and that of one who makes himself rich and has nothing, are totally different. They are both good lessons, though.

Does מִתְעַשֵּׁר imply pretense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two verbs in Prov 13:7, one about becoming rich and the other about becoming poor.  Both have identical grammatical forms as follows:

- מִ֭תְעַשֵּׁר = Hithpael masculine singular form of עָשַׁר = to be or become rich.  This means it should be translated in the reflexive (or middle voice) meaning, "to make oneself rich".
- מִ֝תְרוֹשֵׁ֗שׁ = Hithpael masculine singular form of רוּשׁ = to be or become poor.  This means it should be translated in the reflexive (or middle voice) meaning, "to make oneself poor".

Now, whatever one says about one of these verbs must be said about the other because they are placed on exact contrasting parallelism.  That is, we must either translate the proverb as either:

> There is one who makes himself rich yet has nothing; and one who makes
> himself poor yet has great riches

or

> There is one who pretends to be rich yet has nothing; and one who pretends to be
> poor yet has great riches

However, one cannot translate as per some versions that want half of one and half of the other.  Grammatically and semantically, I prefer the former.

Comment: +1 poetic structure is the most significant context in proverbs, which has short sayings that can stand alone.